# 1 IV, two levels; 2 DVs (one post-test only, one pre-test & post-test). Have some ideas but unsure. Cliche question but:What stats test to use?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I'm working on a proposal and trying to get my stats tests right. Been doing some reading and while I'm beginning to get a better grasp of things, I'm still a little puzzled as to what stats test to use.

Here is my situation:
I am doing a study in which I want to study the effect of a game on students performance and motivation:

IV: Two levels; Treatment and Control.

DV: Performance will be measured using a pre-test post-test maths quiz.

For motivation however, I'm only doing a post-test. (If anyone is curious, I'm using Keller's Instructional Material Motivation Survery (IMMS)). The reason being is that it measures motivation in relation to the game (which is what I want). Hence, a pre test would not be possible as it contains items such as "The game is attractive to me" something that can only be measured after treatment.

Hence, one DV will have pre-test & post-test scores while the other will only have post-test scores

The possible ways of designing my study that I have seen so far are:

1. MANCOVA on the post-treatment scores (motivation and performance), with pre-treatment score (performance) as a covariate and treatment as an independent variable. [I don't even know if this makes sense. The fact that I don't have a pre-test for motivation is kinda throwing me off]
2. Mixed MANOVA - Two within-subject factor (pre vs. post-test) and one between-subject factor (treatment vs. control). [Again, thrown off because I don't have a pre-test for motivation. Should I put my pre-test for motivation as 0 then? I thinking that way because their motivation WOULD technically be zero as they have never played the game before]
3. MANOVA - 1 IV (treatment and control), 2 DV (post-pre performance & motivation)

That's what I have so far. What do you think of the above and ss there a (hopefully) simpler design I could go with?